# retrieving mails from IMAP server?

Tags: ios, cocoa, email, imap, mailcore

I'm trying to read a message from gmail IMAP server using MailCore API. I'm working on this since two days but couldn't solve it. Help me with that how can I retrieve my first email from inbox folder and display it as a string. My code is:

```
    CTCoreFolder *inbox=[[CTCoreFolder alloc]initWithPath:@"INBOX" inAccount:account];
    NSArray *messageSet=[inbox messagesFromSequenceNumber:1 to:0    withFetchAttributes:CTFetchAttrEnvelope];
    NSString *s=[[messageSet objectAtIndex:0] body];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GMail root folder is called `"[Gmail]"` not `"INBOX"` as is otherwise common.

Comment: I've solved it as much that it can retrieve mails from yahoo and aol but not gmail.. I think this was the problem.

Comment: "[Gmail]" isn't working... can you suggest me something else... I want to access inbox folder.

Comment: Try with just an empty string, or select a function which doesn't require a folder name.

Comment: It's not working with empty string. I'm using MailCore API and it has a single function for accessing a folder.

Comment: @Sikander what settings do you use for yahoo and aol with MailCore?

Comment: @Honcheng for yahoo I use..

[account connectToServer:@"imap.mail.yahoo.com" port:993 connectionType:CTConnectionTypeTLS authType:IMAP_AUTH_TYPE_PLAIN login:email.text password:pasword.text];

  And for aol...

[account connectToServer:@"imap.aol.com" port:993 connectionType:CTConnectionTypeTLS authType:IMAP_AUTH_TYPE_PLAIN login:email password:pasword];